# AWS - bash - sigv4 - SignatureDoesNotMatch - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, authentication, amazon-s3, curl

I'm encountering an issue with an AWS S3 request where the error message indicates a signature mismatch:

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

I've followed the troubleshooting steps provided in the AWS documentation and compared the generated signature with the one in the request, but they appear to be the same.

Here's a simplified version of the script:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=

AWS_SERVICE='s3'
AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL="xxxx-xxx.s3-accesspoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

AWS_S3_PATH="/xxx/xxx.zip"

CURRENT_DATE_DAY="$(date -u '+%Y%m%d')"
CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601="${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}T$(date -u '+%H%M%S')Z"
HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH="$(echo -n | openssl dgst -sha256 |cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS="host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token"
HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_URI="${AWS_S3_PATH}"

HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_HEADERS="host:${AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL}\nx-amz-content-sha256:${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}\nx-amz-date:${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}\nx-amz-security-token:${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}"

HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST="GET\n${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_URI}\n\n${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_HEADERS}\n\n${HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS}\n${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}"

#echo ${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST}

# Create the signature.
# Usage:
#   create_signature

hmac_sha256() {
  KEY="$1"
  DATA="$2"
  echo -n "$DATA" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "$KEY" | sed 's/^.* //'
}

hash_sha256() {
  echo -n "${1}" | openssl dgst -sha256 | sed 's/^.* //'
}


DATE_KEY=$(hmac_sha256 key:"AWS4$SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" $CURRENT_DATE_DAY)
DATE_REGION_KEY=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:$CURRENT_DATE_DAY $AWS_REGION)
DATE_REGION_SERVICE_KEY=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:$DATE_REGION_KEY $AWS_SERVICE) 
HEX_KEY=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:$DATE_REGION_SERVICE_KEY "aws4_request")


# Generate canonical request hash
CANONICAL_REQUEST_HASH=$(hash_sha256 ${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST})
#echo ${CANONICAL_REQUEST_HASH}

stringToSign="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}\n${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}/${AWS_REGION}/${AWS_SERVICE}/aws4_request\n${CANONICAL_REQUEST_HASH}"

echo ${stringToSign}

# Generate signature
SIGNATURE=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:$HEX_KEY ${stringToSign})

#echo ${SIGNATURE}

HTTP_REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}/${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}/${AWS_REGION}/${AWS_SERVICE}/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=${HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS}, Signature=${SIGNATURE}"


echo ${HTTP_REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}

echo "Downloading https://${AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL}${AWS_S3_PATH} to guid.zip"

curl --location "https://${AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL}${AWS_S3_PATH}" \
    -H "Authorization: ${HTTP_REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}" \
    -H "x-amz-content-sha256: ${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}" \
    -H "X-Amz-Date: ${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}" \
    -H "X-Amz-Security-Token: ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" \
```

I have checked the following:

Date Format Consistency: The date formats are consistent.
Canonical Request String: The canonical request string matches the expected value.
String to Sign: The string to sign matches the expected value.
Signature Calculation: The calculated signature matches the expected value.
Authorization Header: The generated authorization header matches the expected value.
I'm using temporary credentials obtained through AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, and the role, token, and other parameters seem to be correctly set.

I cannot use AWS libraries or cli, only plain HTTP curl is my option. Is there an alternate way also to this, that would also help.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or can someone provide additional insights into what might be causing the signature mismatch?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There were two main errors with your code.  You are signing the strings with `\n` instead of applying the escape characters to actually sign a newline, and also you weren't actually using the secret key, but rather passing in an undefined variable.

Also, it's worth pointing out, when you say that your string to sign matches the expected value, you must have been ignoring the final canonical hash, as that couldn't have been correct.  This string should match byte-for-byte the returned value from AWS.

I would highly recommend using `set -ue` when debugging bash scripts so that you can catch typos quickly.

Here's a correct version of the code:

```
CURRENT_DATE_DAY="$(date -u '+%Y%m%d')"
CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601="${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}T$(date -u '+%H%M%S')Z"
HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH="$(echo -n | openssl dgst -sha256 |cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS="host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token"
HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_URI="${AWS_S3_PATH}"

HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_HEADERS="host:${AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL}\nx-amz-content-sha256:${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}\nx-amz-date:${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}\nx-amz-security-token:${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}"
HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST="GET\n${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_URI}\n\n${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST_HEADERS}\n\n${HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS}\n${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}"

hmac_sha256() {
  KEY="$1"
  DATA="$2"
  # Fix: Use of '-e' so that newline characters are properly converted
  echo -en "$DATA" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "$KEY" | sed 's/^.* //'
}

hash_sha256() {
  # Fix: Use of '-e' so that newline characters are properly converted
  echo -en "${1}" | openssl dgst -sha256 | sed 's/^.* //'
}


# Fix: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY is used instead of the undefined SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
DATE_KEY=$(hmac_sha256 key:"AWS4$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" $CURRENT_DATE_DAY)
# Fix: DATE_KEY is used instead of the raw value CURRENT_DATE_DAY 
DATE_REGION_KEY=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:$DATE_KEY $AWS_REGION)
DATE_REGION_SERVICE_KEY=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:$DATE_REGION_KEY $AWS_SERVICE) 
HEX_KEY=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:$DATE_REGION_SERVICE_KEY "aws4_request")

# Generate canonical request hash
# Fix: Quote string so that it's passed as one arg
CANONICAL_REQUEST_HASH=$(hash_sha256 "${HTTP_CANONICAL_REQUEST}")
stringToSign="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}\n${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}/${AWS_REGION}/${AWS_SERVICE}/aws4_request\n${CANONICAL_REQUEST_HASH}"

# Generate signature
# Fix: Quote string so that it's passed as one arg
SIGNATURE=$(hmac_sha256 hexkey:$HEX_KEY "${stringToSign}")

HTTP_REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}/${CURRENT_DATE_DAY}/${AWS_REGION}/${AWS_SERVICE}/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=${HTTP_REQUEST_SIGNED_HEADERS}, Signature=${SIGNATURE}"

echo "Downloading https://${AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL}${AWS_S3_PATH} to guid.zip"
curl --location "https://${AWS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL}${AWS_S3_PATH}" \
    -H "Authorization: ${HTTP_REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}" \
    -H "x-amz-content-sha256: ${HTTP_REQUEST_PAYLOAD_HASH}" \
    -H "X-Amz-Date: ${CURRENT_DATE_ISO8601}" \
    -H "X-Amz-Security-Token: ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" \
```

Comment: i identified and fixed the mistakes you mentioned. but I was able to solve this some hours back, i used the signature calculation part from this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332188/hmac-sha-256-for-a-signed-aws-request/64091586#comment136670198_64091586.
Thanks for pointing out the mistakes